# In "martire di qualcosa", si può usare "di" come complemento d'agente?

Tags: word-usage, synonym

Nel parlare di alcuni caduti antifascisti, mi è capitato di riferirmi a loro come *martiri del fascismo*, col significato di *persone rese martiri dal fascismo*. Tuttavia, nel rileggere una seconda volta il testo, ho notato l'ambiguità dell'espressione, che può essere intesa come *persone rese martiri perché associate al fascismo*. Perciò, mi sono posto il dubbio: **è legittimo/consigliabile far seguire "martire di" dall'agente?** Il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/martire/) riporta un solo esempio di questo utilizzo, contro una decina di esempi dove utilizza "di" come complemento di causa.

Inoltre, **come posso disambiguare tra i due utilizzi? C'è un'espressione equivalente a "martire di" + agente?**

Comment: La discussione generata da questa domanda mi sembra interessante perché nel libro ***Privo di titolo*** di Andrea Camilleri ho letto due frasi che sembrano fare un uso contraddittorio (nel senso che si sta qui discutendo) della costruzione "martire di". In questo romanzo, basato in un fatto di cronaca, un comunista è accusato ingiustamente dell'assassinio di un giovane fascista che viene subito dichiarato come il "martire fascista della Sicilia". Poi si scoprirà che tale martire è stato ucciso da un altro fascista.

Comment: Questa frase appare in un giornale fascista giusto dopo la morte del giovane: "Ma, oh miracolo!, è stato come se il giovine Martire della ferocia comunista abbia voluto allontanare da noi altro sangue: difatti, nel corso della mattinata, pur persistendo una tensione altissima, ..."

Comment: Quest'altra frase proviene da un altro giornale, da un articolo che racconta un atto di omaggio al "martire" tenuto giusto dopo la vittoria elettorale del Fascismo per maggioranza assoluta: "Sul nastro della corona che è stata deposta sulla tomba c'era scritto: «A Lillino, Martire dell'Idea che ha vinto»."

Comment: Peccato che parte della discussione sia sparita!

Comment: A pensarci meglio, l'uso di "martire di" in queste due frasi non mi sembra veramente contraddittorio perché in tutte e due ha senso sostituire la parola "martire" con "testimone".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martire, come hai giustamente citato da Treccani, significa 'testimone', chi si sacrifica per un ideale. Col signficato di 'vittima' è errato o regionale, e si è diffuso nell'esempio citato.

Dal [sito della Crusca](http://forum.accademiadellacrusca.it/forum_8/interventi/3193.shtml.html):

> **martire del fascismo**
>
> Giammai. Martire significa "testimone", non "vittima". I martiri del
>   fascismo sono coloro che sono morti (e
>   qualcuno ce ne fu) per quella che si chiamava "rivoluzione fascista" e
>   cui si dedicavano, in genere collettivamente, vie e piazze. Sul numero
>   dei "martiri fascisti" non saprei darle ragguagli. Una curiosità:
>   Urbisaglia, prima della guerra, era chiamata ufficialmente "Urbisaglia
>   Bonservizi" in omaggio a un "martire fascista". Io sarei più parco nel
>   tributare il titolo di martire: morire per un ideale è nobil cosa,
>   essere perseguitati per motivi politici o religiosi è un'afflizione
>   che domanda virtù, ma morire per testimoniare è altra cosa.

Nel meridione è diffuso l'uso di 'martire' col significato di 'perseguitato', 'tormentato' : "M'ha fatto martire per tutta la serata!"

Non è forse un caso che l'unico esempio citato sia di Pirandello. Forse la parola che cerchi, a seconda del contesto, è 'perseguitato' o (se morto) 'vittima'.

Comment: Anche se la citazione dal sito della Crusca proviene da un forum lì ospitato e quindi non è “ufficiale”, contiene spunti interessanti (anche negli altri interventi, oltre a quello riportato qui), tra cui un foscoliano “martire della Democrazia” che conferma nuovamente che “martire di X” è chi soffre per X, non ad opera di X.

Comment: Attenzione però che in Italia esistono vie ai Martiri della Resistenza, della Libertà, della Liberazione, delle Foibe, del Fascismo, dei Lager, etc. Gli ultimi tre casi si spiegherebbero così: sarebbero persone martirizzate **nelle** foibe, **nel contesto storico del** fascismo, **nei** lager, etc. Io ho l'impressione che lo slittamento semantico possa in parte essere dovuto a regionalismi e in parte a revisionismo storico che sterilizza le parole e svuota i concetti che le parole veicolano. Per evitare ambiguità io direi _martiri dell'antifascismo_ o _martiri della Resistenza_.

Comment: Da ricordare anche che il fascismo stesso dedicò monumenti ai propri martiri, i martiri del fascismo…

Comment: Non madrelingua qui. Non riesco a vedere nessuna relazione tra i significati più usuali di "testimone" e "martire". Il primo è testimone di un evento, ad esempio un crimine, il secondo si sacrifica per una causa. Questo significato  "testimone" di "martire" non è solo biblico / letterario?